# Frequencies / percentages of multiple binary variables by group with dplyr

Tags: r

I am trying to get a table that would display the percentages of several binary variables by a grouping variable. This is the example of the data I have and what I tried.

```
var1 <- c(0,1,0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
var2 <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0)
var3 <- c(0, 0, 0, 1,1,0, 0, 0)
gender <- c("female", "male", "female", "male", "male", "male", "female", "male")
other <- c(1, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5)

data<- cbind(var1, var2, var3, gender, other) %>% as.data.frame()



data %>%
  group_by(gender) %>%
  summarise (n = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = n / sum(n))
```

This the code returns.

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  gender     n  freq
  <fct>  <int> <dbl>
1 female     3 0.375
2 male       5 0.625
```

What I would like to see is the percentage of the respondents within each variable that answered 1 by gender (numbers are just for the example, as I don't know them, and that is what I would like to find out).

```
  gender     n total   freqvar1  freqvar2  freqvar3  
1 female     3        0.375       0.456     0.300
2 male       5        0.625       0.544     0.700
```

Many thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After grouping by 'gender', get the 'total' with `n()`, then loop over the 'var' variables with `across`, get the `mean` of logical `vector`

```
library(dplyr) # 1.0.0
data %>% 
   group_by(gender) %>% 
       summarise(total = n(), 
            across(starts_with('var'), ~ mean(. == 1)))
```

Comment: actually, after having played around with it, I have another question - how would I make this code more generic and also applicable to factor variables ? i.e. 1) instead of running across all variables that start with a specific string, how can i run the function across all variables I have selected in a pipe? and 2) what would me an equialent to the mean function, if the variables were not binary but with multiple categories?

Comment: @ievasieva instead of `starts_with`, if you want all variables, then specify `across(everything(), ~ mean(.))` i assume those are numeric columns?